# Magento 2: Errors on running setup:di:compile after upgrade from Magento version 2.4.3 to 2.4.5:

Tags: setup-di-compile, magento2.4.4, version, version-upgrade

I am getting this error after upgrading Magento version 2.4.3 to 2.4.5
[image]

I am unable to find any solution. please help.

Comment: Look like you have a module which reference that class.

Comment: Run the `composer install` again to install missed files in the `vendor` folder.

Comment: Can you please update full error? just copy and paste the error in question

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `vendor` folder and run `composer install`, then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **vendor** folder manually and again run **composer install**, then run all the commands

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:com
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps :

Check your elastic Search
Delete or rename your vendor directory and run `composer install` and the composer update

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:di:co
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

ans this not fix the issue then remove composer.lock and run composer install and `composer update`